# Swift 3 custom touch motion to trigger action

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

Im just wondering if there is guide for swift to perform a custom touch motion.
Example : draw a free hand circle in the screen and it will unlock the phone/trigger any action.

I tried search for the solution but it doesn't guide me to the path i want. Thanks for your links sharing and suggestions.

Comment: Asking for a tutorial recommendation is off-topic on StackOverflow.  I highly recommend to take a look through the [help] to see what kinds of questions you can ask here.

Comment: @Lexi Thanks for your reply. All i need is some keywords that i can go for. Anyway, i will go through that help center. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you question is divided into 2 parts and I'll answer them both.

1- What you are looking for is UIGestureRecognizer where it'll recognize a gesture and do an action accordingly. Here is a link taht will help you out! https://www.raywenderlich.com/76020/using-uigesturerecognizer-with-swift-tutorial

2- Unlocking the phone is impossible without jailbreak. Your gestures are bound to your application. If you want your gestures to work outside the app then your only way is jailbreak

Hope this helps!

Comment: Don't answer off-topic questions.